The image field in the blog front matter, how to use the image in the assets folder in the same directory
I try to set the front matter like this
draft: true
slug: otOARU_mJTlg
title: XXX
image: assets/images/otOARU_mJTlg-cover.webp

But the picture can't be found.
I want to use pictures with relative paths like this
image: assets/images/otOARU_mJTlg-cover.webp

Question Addressed (Docusaurus 3.0, 2023)
I've researched this question before and found that the image tag in Docusaurus frontmatter is for the meta tag.
The image meta tag "is shown when you share the link on Twitter, Discord, etc," per this closed GitHub issue.
Frontmatter Image Tag ≠ Blog Feature Image
Put simply, the image tag does not add a feature image to your blogs. The image tag displays in image when the associated link is shared on social media.

I, too, wish defining a blog feature image was as intuitive as defining the image tag in Docusaurus frontmatter.
